# How to use MUI Datagrid without ID?

Tags: material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

My table don't have ID column. Data from that table is coming from an API. I have no control over it. Otherwise, I would have modified that data to include id column.

My table consist column representing something like for eg. name, age, city. It don't need id column too. But I need Datagrid for pagination, sorting, filtering. Otherwise, I could have used MUI Table component .

So, does any one know any workaround to use DataGrid table without id? Or passing some dummy id attached to table to make DataGrid table work?

I tried searching google for answer. I got redirected to using custom ID, which I don't need. However, I expect the table to display without ID.